# How to upload multiple time a drawable image on firebase storage?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I would like to know if is it possible to upload multiple time the same image taken from the drawable images on firebase storage in such a way that on the storage the image appears multiple times under different names. What I do is:

```
imageUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.project/"+R.drawable.error);
riversRef = storageRef.child("images/" + imageUri.getLastPathSegment()+ "_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(imageUri);
```

but everytime I use this in the storage does not appear any new images, just the first. Probably because having the same name on the storage (2131230900) and being the same image the storage ignore it. The result I want to obtain is that I have the two identical images took from the drawable of my project but in the storage they results as 2 different names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `riversRef` is a reference to a specific location/file in Cloud Storage. If you call `putFile` multiple times on the same reference, you're writing to the same location multiple times, so you'll indeed end up with only one file

To write multiple unique files, you'll need to create a separate unique reference for each file. Something like:

```
riversRef = storageRef.child("images/" + file.getLastPathSegment() + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

By adding the timestamp to the name of the file on Storage here, we end up with unique references if you call this multiple times. Alternatively something like this would also work:

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    riversRef = storageRef.child("images/" + file.getLastPathSegment() + "_" + i);
    uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);
}
```

So now we're just adding a counter to each file name in Cloud Storage.

Comment: I tried this but when the program launch uploadTask=riversRef.putFile(file) I get the error: could not locate file for uploading:android.resource://com.example.project/2131230900. In the storage does not appear a new image with the new reference (done by adding the timestamp)

Comment: That means that `file` doesn't exist, which means that your original code likely also didn't work. I intentionally changed nothing about that part of your code, as it's unclear from what you posted where `file` comes from.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I made the code more clear. However the error it's still the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean there. Are you saying you can't upload a single file?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be clearer. If i don't put + " _ " + i the image is uploaded only the first time. The other times being identical object probably are ignored from the storage and so there is a single (the first) image in the storage. If I add + " _ " + i as suggested i can't upload any image at all. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: That's unexpected. I wonder it it's a local file access issue. Are there any error messages in the logcat output right after the uploads (try to) start?

Comment: Hey @DanteAligante.  Are there any error messages in the logcat output right after the uploads (try to) start?